# 5 V switching regulator problems

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, decoupling-capacitor, inrush-current

I have a circuit with two supplies, a 19 V supply for stepper motors, and a 5 V supply for driving the ATMEGA644, 3 stepper motor driver daughter boards, a Bluetooth LE daughter board, and two WS2812B RGB LEDs.

With two supplies everything worked, but I really wanted to get it down to just one supply. So I did another version of the board using just the 19 V supply and a VX78-500 switching regulator. I used their recommended input and output caps (but not the low noise version that include some extra inductors).

I have a 100 μF electrolytic on the 5 V rail. I'm not 100% sure if that's a good idea, but it's well below the max. capacitive load for the VX78-500 which is 680 μF and I thought it might help with noise.

I also have three 100 μF electrolytic on the 19 V line next to the stepper driver boards for the same reason.

When I first turned things on I noticed the WS2812b'd flashed slightly but everything was fine. That didn't happen on the two-supply version of the board. However, on maybe the 3rd or 4th time I turned it on the Bluetooth LE daughter board died, which is kind of surprising because it's got its own on-board 3.3 V LDO regulator.

I don't know that much about supply best practices/inrush current, etc. I knew my new setup would be noisier using a switching supply/being down stream from the same supply as the steppers. Any ideas what is going on? That flashing makes me think there's a bad spike happening at switch on time. It seems weird that the ATmega644 is still ticking but the BTLE daughter board died. How do I trouble shoot this?

Are those 100 μF caps just a bad idea in general? Does my circuit need some other form of protection?

Those daughter boards are $19 so I don't want to blow out too many of them in a search for the solution. Here is a pic of the PCB. I'm sure I'm just making some noob mistake, but I'd really like this one-supply version to work.

[image: PCB With One Supply]

Ignore where that says 12 V, it's really 19 V. *blush*

Here are the two sheets of the schematic as well:

[image: The first sheet of schematic]

[image: Second sheet of schematic]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please add the schematic, as this is more helpful than the PCB screenshot.

Comment: You PCB picture isn't very helpful here. As Daniel said, please, provide the schematic. 100 uF capacitor is ok, nothing wrong, I would add more closer to the logic ICs. Also did you use decoupling capacitors (about 0.1 uF)? What is the powers consumption on 5V line? Don't you think tat 500 mA from DC-DC converter could be not enough for such kind of schematics (only RGB leds need at least 50 mA each; may be even more)? What is you 19V supply output power? Is is possible, that it has bad ripples itself, which you didn't see, when used second power supply?

Comment: "bluetooth LE daughter board" died - What is this card exactly? What is its power requirement, especially max input voltage? Did you check transient voltages on all rails (+5V most suspect) upon power-on process?

Comment: It's this adafruit bluetooth LE board:  https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/downloads

Comment: Which seems to be using the MIC5225 as a regulator that says it's ok up to 16v.  Of course something else may have been killed like the level shifting chip, etc.

Comment: The 19v supply is a 90watt supply.  (To support driving the steppers) but the the thing died before I got around to populating the stepper drivers/driving motors, so the 19v supply is definitely not overloaded.  Each of the LEDs max out at 60ma I think the Nordic BT chip uses something like max 14ma.  So I don't think I'm pressing up toward the limits of the supply without even having the drivers populated.  Not having enough headroom might be an issue I run into at some point, but I don't think it's what's cause my current problem.

Comment: @KurtSchaefer Unfortunately, nobody can tell you what the problem is based on you details. Sometimes electronics can die without any visible reasons. Designing hardware you should always be aware that something can go wrong and it would require more time/materials/costs to make it working. First of all you should check you power rails with oscilloscope, starting from 19V output, then 5V output and then go further, check level shifters, short circuits on PCB and so on. What I can tell you, that this is not normal behavior, you definitely have something working wrong.

Comment: @KurtSchaefer Relatively easy and fast test - try to replace input power supply (let say, 19V to 12V) and DC-DC converter with linear regulator (7805 etc.) or other model of DC-DC converter (MP1584 etc.).

Comment: I can say that everything ran fine under 5v supplied by my programming header.  I didn't populate the BTLE board until I could confirm the cpu was working and programable.  Then I populated the Bluetooth board and confirmed it was working.  Then I switched over to 19v and tried running it and even that was fine, but I noticed the funny flickering of the LEDs when I powered on and then on maybe the 3 or 4th power up the BT board died.  (I wasn't powering it off and on like crazy, just eventually the BT board died.)

Comment: @cyclone125 Oh that's an interesting idea.   Fall back to a linear regulator just to see if something else is causing problems during power up.  I'll have to fish around and see if I have a TO-220 7805 some place.  Seems seems possible.

Comment: I don't have a storage scope but my fluke's peak mode says 5.22v on the 5v rail.  19v supply looks pretty clean on the scope.  The 5v rail has a 60 uSec long dip periodically.

Answer (score 1):

> That flashing makes me think there's a bad spike happening at switch
>   on time.

I think you are on right track. The problem is likely in start-up transients.

From the PCB layout: it is customary to place a de-coupling capacitor in close proximity to every Vin entry point to any sub-block, be it a IC or an external module. There is no cap at the entry to NRF8001, the module which has died.

I also tried to imagine the shape of bottom ground plane (I assume it is there). It looks like it is badly traversed by many signal traces, so the actual ground integrity looks very questionable.

So I am afraid this board has strong transients that killed your NRF module. Try to put a 10-uF ceramic 0805 capacitor between Vin and GND pins on the NRF connector, and maybe put some 5-V voltage suppressor.

Comment: I guess it's true I have caps by all the other daughter boards, but not that one.  I always do that for chips, but I kind of assumed that since boards like that have their own local caps it would be ok.  Good to know I shouldn't assume that.  So you think the spike is on the 5v rail?   What sort of 5v suppressor.  Like a zener on the 5v rail?  Sorry I'm just clue less about power rail protection stuff.   Do I put that near the regulator, or down stream near the components?   I guess I'll have to read up on those.  Thanks!